# ASP CompareValidator always returns false for two dates no matter what

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two text controls, one is the start date and one is the end date. I need to validate the user input on these dates, simple, the start must be less than or equal to the end date.

I have the following code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="calendar" TabIndex="5"></asp:TextBox>    

<asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" CssClass="calendar" TabIndex="7"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CompareValidator ID="cvDate" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" Type="Date" 
    ControlToValidate="txtEndDate" ControlToCompare="txtStartDate"
    ErrorMessage="End date must be greater than or equal to start date!" 
    runat="server" Display="None"/>

<asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="cvDate_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server"
    CloseImageUrl="images/close.gif" Enabled="True" HighlightCssClass="formFieldHighligherOnValidation"
    TargetControlID="cvDate" WarningIconImageUrl="images/warning.gif">
</asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```

The problem is that the validation is always failing no matter what dates I pick in the UI. I don’t understand why, I have looked at various posts here and other forums and this appears to be the correct approach.
Thoughts?

Edit:

The dates are actually just pure strings in the text box. I am using the AjaxControlKit calender. This explains why when I compare these strings i am getting such weird results. I'd like to keep the current calender as it looks nicer than the regular ASP one but then I am stuck with the problem how do I compare the dates.

Comment: may i know the format of date in textbox? after selection from the calendar

Comment: Not sure I understand. If user picks the date it will be like "20 April, 2012". Does the calendar date not just get formated as a string in the text box.

Comment: I would use process of elimination and start by removing  the extender. After that, try using the `CompareValidator` just to check the validity of `txtStartDate`, without comparing it to `txtEndDate`. Keep simplifying it until you figure out where the culprit is.

Comment: @MichaelHollywood: Include the calendar extenders in your markup, or whatever you're using to display the calendars.

Comment: Ok, i'll try that. Though I might just be quicker creating a custom validator.